# How to refresh models and tables from database in cakephp 3?

Tags: cakephp

I changed my database directly from phpmyadmin ,; and now I want my cakephp application to be updated , I mean that all my database tables being traduced in  my cakephp app ; is there a command line that helps for that please ?

Comment: It depends what you changed

Comment: Can you pls elaborate your problem. If you have changed database directly from phpmyadmin then you can also truncate all tables from there. can't you?

Comment: I changed columns of tables ,; I added ones and droped ones , and specially added some relationships between tables  ,; Well I found a solution by baking models again but I found this is not professional cuz I practically regenerate model and I lose what I've made in this models(I mean functions )

Comment: @LinaHammami yes by baking models all the models are generated again. If you have backup then you can copy all the important functions again the the models.

Comment: yeah that's what I did ,; if it's the right way ,; you can post your answer and I'll mark it

Comment: You must [**clear the model cache**](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/console-and-shells/schema-cache.html) (`tmp/cache/models`) after making changes to the schema, no need to rebake if you don't actually _need/want_ things to be rebaked (rules/properties/fixtures/etc added/updated/removed). See also **https://github.com/cakephp/cakephp/issues/12214**

Comment: As @ndm said you must clear your cache. I'd use a Redis cache in development so you can just run `redis-cli flushall`. For handling actual migration with table schema use https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/phinx.html